# How can one parse this in Yaml?

Tags: ruby, parsing, yaml

Suppose I have this example :

```
Example:
  number:
    cuarenta
    cuarenta y uno
    cuarenta y dos
    cuarenta y tres
    cuarenta y cuatro
    cuarenta y cinco
    cuarenta y seis
    cuarenta y siete
    cuarenta y ocho
    cuarenta y nueve
```

And I'd like to parse this so that I have each of those numbers together like "cuaranta y nueve". I'm having trouble visualizing how to do that since in YAML, you're turned a string associated with "noun".

My yaml parser looks like this :

```
  File.open(Rails.root + 'lib/words/yamlicious.yml', 'r') do |file|
    YAML::load(file).each do |topic, word_types|
      temp_topic = Topic.create! name: topic
      temp_words = word_types.map{|type, words| words.split(' ').map {|word| Word.create type: type, word: word, topics: [temp_topic] } }
      temp_topic.words << temp_words
    end
  end
```

Notice the `split` part would ruin that because then I would get a word created per my example as three words "cuarenta", "y", and "uno".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To preserve newlines, you have to use the [pipe character](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#single_ending_newline):

```
Example:
  number: |
    cuarenta
    cuarenta y uno
    cuarenta y dos
    …
```

Now you can `split("\n")`

Comment: Ah geez I had not seen this! Thanks Stefan!