# Yaml, am I doing this right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, yaml

I have yaml like this :

```
Numbers Five:
  noun:
    cuarenta y uno
    cuarenta y dos
    cuarenta y tres
    cuarenta y cuatro
    cuarenta y cinco
    cuarenta y seis
    cuarenta y siete
    cuarenta y ocho
    cuarenta y nueve
```

Is this the proper way to write this? I say this because I'm having a really difficult time grabbing a "noun" in its complete three word part. Or what I see as the entire line. Instead, its producing a hash with all the nouns listed, but nothing to necessarily separate them.

Should I be using commas to separate words, or is there a way to parse these correctly without adding anything more to the yaml?

My parsing structure :

```
YAML::load(file).each do |topic, word_types|
  word_types.map do |type, words|
    words.split(' ').map do |word|
    #            ^ This is my ghetto way to do it, but would not work appropriately for a three word line.
```

Comment: How come you've so many values for a single key?

Comment: Anyway, did you try `each_line`?

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for the response. Your first comment could be addressing a problem with how I think I should be writing the yaml in the first place. That might be the source of the issue. I want to create objects where all those words have the attribute noun. Also, did try `each_line`, but it returns thinking that all of them are within the same line. :(

Comment: Hard to understand the final goal, but as you said, use conmas to separate values, it remains the easiest means

Comment: Cool, that's what I was thinking. Thanks apneadiving. I invite you to provide that as an answer if you wish.

Comment: This is the way YAML works, you have to add a pipe character in order to preserve newlines, see [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948132/how-can-one-parse-this-in-yaml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, csv is the easiest way to proceed. One question remains: is yaml the best format to store your data then? :)

Comment: What else would you suggest? :D

Comment: I originally did that. But I just like the visual clarity of yaml over csv.

Comment: Yep, and it has better key/value support btw.